# Where is the journal on the Extended file system?

Tags: filesystems

Where exactly is the journal on the EXT3/EXT4 file system, ive searched around and cant find a good answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, it is a regular file controlled by an inode, but the inode does not have a directory entry.  If you do `tune2fs -l /dev/$ext3partition` it will mention the "Journal inode" -- usually it seems to be number 8.  You should be able to use `debugfs` to get more details.

Answer (score 1):

Journal is the file located on the root directory with the name .journal or something like that. Just enable the journalling for your filesystem using the tune2fs and see the root directory. It will be a hidden file.